# SVN condition-based batch file

Tags: svn, batch-file, command-line

I am trying to write a .bat file which will take an SVN update (Command: `svn update C:/svn/`) for me,but some times it is not working as expected its give error like `svn: E155004: Working copy 'C:\svn' locked`.

So am trying to write a **condition** based code that will check if svn update is successful or not if not successful by above mentioned error so my .bat file should run svn clean up first and again take update. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if `svn` returns errorlevels and if so then this may work.  The `svn clean up` syntax needs to be checked.

```
@echo off
:loop
svn update C:\svn\
  if errorlevel 1 (
     svn clean up
     goto :loop
  )
pause
```